# Is it okay and safe to store pulses, grains, rice etc. in these containers?

Tags: food-safety, storage, grains, containers, pulses

During coronavirus lockdown, I can't buy containers. But I've some empty boxes of Protinex powder like these: https://www.amazon.in/Protinex-400-g-Tasty-Chocolate/dp/B01MS489AE I guess it is made from metal.

So is it safe to store these things in it? Or it will be harmful to these things?

EDIT: I bought that product a long time ago, and now it seems like packaging is changed in the link I provided. So I'm afraid it would be not ideal to expect new answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When storing nonperishable dry foods, such as pulses or grains or protein powder, you want the container to be reasonably airtight and impermeable, which that container appears to be. There aren't any other major considerations. Should be fine.